# HTML Line Breaks

Tags: html

I'm having trouble putting line breaks in HTML. Also, in Chrome and Opera the first bullet point is reversed. Firefox and Internet Explorer do it correctly.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="line"></div>
<div id="product_details" class="block_center">
    <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerPop.png" class="left" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%" />
    <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerHum.png" class="right" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%"/>
    <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerHiss.png" class="left" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%"/>
    <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerNoiseGate.png" class="right" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%"/>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<ul class="productsBullets">
    <li>Removes Pops and Clicks</li>
    <li>Eliminates Hum</li>
</ul>
```

Here's the site:

[enter link description here](http://blazeaudio.com/products/Record_Cleaner.html)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not good at creating links to code. There is a <br /> <br />  and <ul class="productsBullets">....

Comment: Line breaks in HTML are just normal whitespace.  If you want an explicit line break, you can use `<br/>`.  Rarely this is needed though... consider margins as necessary.

Comment: What do you mean line breaks? Do you want the images to be on there own lines?

Comment: if those images are css floated, then that's why. floating removes the images from various positioning calculations, including "line breaks". you'd need a `<br style="clear: both" />`

Comment: Also if IE is doing something 'correctly' and the other browsers are not - that is a sign of a serious problem!!!  IE is usually way behind 'web standards' and is a pet peve to all web developers.

Comment: within the source code there is a <br /> tag within the <ul><li>code used outside of the <li>'s and this will not take any effect, remove this? Also you need to add any line breaks after the images as they are just going to align next to each other and this include the ul after them to add a few break points before the ul and after the images or also surroud the images in a blank <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned your four images an the ul are just displaying along each other, so surround the images in their own div then add a few line breaks after that then the ul or us css on the image div to give it some spacing EG:

```
   <div id="product_details" class="block_center">
       <!-- image wrapper -->
       <div class="image-wrapper" style="margin: 15px 0;">
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerPop.png" class="left" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%">
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerHum.png" class="right" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%">
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerHiss.png" class="left" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%">
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerNoiseGate.png" class="right" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" style="width:50%">
       </div>
       <!-- end of image wrapper -->

        <ul class="productsBullets">
            <li>Removes Pops and Clicks</li>
            <li>Eliminates Hum</li>
            <li>Reduces Hiss</li>
            <li>Noise Gate Removal</li>
            <li>You must have <strong>RipEditBurn Plus</strong>, <strong>RipEditBurn</strong>, or <strong>Wave Creator</strong> installed on your computer</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I have added the inline style="margin: 15px 0;" for eg but you can add that to a class.

Also lose the extra spacing within your `<li></li>` tags at the end of the content etc, view source to see what i mean.

hope this helps a little

here is a working example might help:

```css
.block_center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;
  max-width: 770px;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 49%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="product_details" class="block_center">
       <!-- image wrapper -->
       <div class="image-wrapper" >
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerPop.png" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record">
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerHum.png"  alt="Power Record" title="Power Record" >
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerHiss.png" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record">
        <img src="http://blazeaudio.com/images/RecordCleanerNoiseGate.png" alt="Power Record" title="Power Record">
       </div>
       <!-- end of image wrapper -->

        <ul class="productsBullets">
            <li>Removes Pops and Clicks</li>
            <li>Eliminates Hum</li>
            <li>Reduces Hiss</li>
            <li>Noise Gate Removal</li>
            <li>You must have <strong>RipEditBurn Plus</strong>, <strong>RipEditBurn</strong>, or <strong>Wave Creator</strong> installed on your computer</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your ul needs to clear the floats. Try this in your layout.css line 90.

```
ul.productsBullets {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.productsBullets {
    float: left;
}
```